# Clean way to schedule execution of code at ${sometime} without reentry, how?

Tags: python

I am new with writing python code and trying to execute code only once in specific time. Sort of polling the time.

Here I want to execute when it is 00:30 AM.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if now.hour == 0 and now.minute == 30:
        print "Hit"    # will use this line to call another function or code
        time.sleep(100)

    time.sleep(5)   # to avoid hogging up cpu
```

Using an infinite loop and sleep(100), 100 secs will be good enough to execute the print only once.

- Is there any more robust way in python to do this?

Comment: check out [python-crontab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab)

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

There certainly are alternatives to your implementation, but it all depends on the context. If you are not going to do any other work between *`<start of script>`* and *`<desired execution time>`* you could simply calculate the number of seconds between the two points, and sleep for that entire duration.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, time as t
from time     import sleep
```

```
def work (): 
    pass
```

```
target = dt.combine (dt.now (), t (hour=10,minute=36,second=30))
secs   = (target - dt.now ()).total_seconds ()
```

One must be aware that using `dt.now ()` and setting the time explicitly the way we are doing above might lead a negative number in `secs` if that time has already passed.

---

---

To compensate for what was mentioned, we will need to make sure that our scheduled execution is in the future (effectively adding one day to our `target` if we must wait until tomorrow):

```
import datetime as datetime_m
from   datetime import datetime as dt, time as t
from       time import sleep
```

```
...
```

```
target = dt.combine (dt.now (), t (hour=0,minute=30,second=0))

if (target < dt.now ()):
    target += datetime_m.timedelta(days=1)
```

```
...
```

---

---

#### Running it in  loop

If you are going to run this in a loop, simply increment the `target` by one day on every iteration, and there's no need to worry about triggering the same work twice.

```
import datetime as datetime_m
from   datetime import datetime as dt, time as t
from       time import sleep

def work ():
    pass

target = dt.combine (dt.now (), t (hour=0,minute=30,second=0))

if (target < dt.now ()):
    target += datetime_m.timedelta (days=1)

while True:
    seconds_until_execution = (target - dt.now ()).total_seconds ()

    sleep (seconds_until_execution)         # wait
    work  ()                                # execute

    target += datetime_m.timedelta (days=1) # queue next
```